# Wordcloud overlay in Tableau Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

Is it possible for word clouds to overlay in a single dashboard?

I have done it for Graphs (Bar Graph) however, I can't seem to do the same for word cloud.

Comment: Hello - how do you mean 'overlay', do you have to physically place one on top of another?

Comment: Yups, and the sheets can change according to the filter parameters

Comment: Then yes, you can do this - what's the exact problem you're having? Are you able to share a sample workbook?